# Is there a way to encapsulate the common Perl functions into their own scripts?

Tags: perl, scripting

I am maintaining several Perl scripts that all have similar code blocks for different functions.  Each time a code block is updated, I have to go through each script and manually make the change.

Is there a way to encapsulate the common functions into their own scripts and call them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are other ways, but they all have severe issues.  Modules are the way to go, and they don't have to be very complicated.  Here is a basic template:

```
package Mod;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';

#list of functions/package variables to automatically export
our @EXPORT = qw(
    always_exported   
); 

#list of functions/package variables to export on request
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
    exported_on_request
    also_exported_on_request
);

sub always_exported { print "Hi\n" }

sub exported_on_request { print "Hello\n" }

sub also_exported_on_request { print "hello world\n" }

1; #this 1; is required, see perldoc perlmod for details
```

Create a directory like `/home/user/perllib`.  Put that code in a file named `Mod.pm` in that directory.  You can use the module like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#this line tells Perl where your custom modules are
use lib '/home/user/perllib';

use Mod qw/exported_on_request/;

always_exported();
exported_on_request();
```

Of course, you can name the file anything you want.  It is good form to name the package the same as file.  If you want to have `::` in the name of the package (like `File::Find`) you will need to create subdirectories in `/home/user/perllib`.  Each `::` is equivalent to a `/`, so `My::Neat::Module` would go in the file `/home/user/perllib/My/Neat/Module.pm`.  You can read more about modules in [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) and more about `Exporter` in [`perldoc Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)

Comment: Thanks, that is more clear than what I have been finding on the web, although I don't understand all the exporter stuff, I understand how to use it from your example.

Answer (score 12):

Put the common functionality in a [module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module). See  [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) for details.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without modules?  I am not very good at perl and I was hoping there was a solution more like javascript-ish.

Comment: You can just make libraries. Again, we cover all of that in my book. :)

Answer (score 2):

About a third of [Intermediate Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102067/) is devoted to just this topic.

Comment: This strikes me as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It strikes me as an answer as much as linking to a module or doc page is an answer.

Comment: @brian: yup, those are pretty much comments too. (If you were referring to Sinan's answer, though, I would say that he at least has the one sentence bullet-point answer of "Put the common stuff in a module." You just say, "My book tells you how to do this." Your response is actually, now that I look at it, a comment on Sinan's answer.)

Comment: Well, that's your opinion, and my mine is mine. Telling people where to find the info they need is my answer, and I'm going to keep answering like that when I think it's  appropriate.

Comment: A link to a book is also useful, but this is more on par with a sales pitch.

Answer (score 0):

Using a module is the most robust way, and learning how to use modules would be helpful.

Less efficient is the [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) function. Extract your code to a separate file, say "mysub.pl", and

```
do 'mysub.pl';
```

This will read and then eval the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
require "some_lib_file.pl";
```

where you would put all your common functions and call them from other scripts which would contain the line above.

For example:

```
146$ cat tools.pl
# this is a common function we are going to call from other scripts
sub util()
{
    my $v = shift;
    return "$v\n";
}
1; # note this 1; the 'required' script needs to end with a true value

147$ cat test.pl
#!/bin/perl5.8 -w
require 'tools.pl';
print "starting $0\n";
print util("asdfasfdas");
exit(0);

148$ cat test2.pl
#!/bin/perl5.8 -w
require "tools.pl";
print "starting $0\n";
print util(1);
exit(0);
```

Then executing `test.pl` and `test2.pl` will yield the following results:

```
149$ test.pl
starting test.pl
asdfasfdas

150$ test2.pl
starting test2.pl
1
```